# Show table row in a same color

Tags: javascript

I want the color of a row depending on the value

Here is the code: but always takes the first color.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable td.xs').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() < 10) {
      $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

html:

```
 <tr class="xs">
    <td class="xs">5/td>
    <td class="xs">10</td>
    <td class="xs">12</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, all the `<td>`s share the same `<tr>`, so the last color set by the loop will win (red in your example, because the last `<td>` has `25`). So either you need to change the colour of the `<td>` or you need to put the `<td>`s in their individual `<tr>`s, or you need to be more specific about which `<td>` in the `<tr>` you want to use.

**Option 1: Change colour of `<td>`:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable td.xs').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() < 10) {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="xs">
    <td class="xs">5</td>
    <td class="xs">10</td>
    <td class="xs">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Option 2: Individual `<tr>`:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable td.xs').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() < 10) {
      $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'green');
    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="xs">
    <td class="xs">5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="xs">
    <td class="xs">10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="xs">
    <td class="xs">12</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: if i don't enclosed tr tag with table tag . i cannot access `$('tr')` ?

Comment: @PraveenKumar What do you mean change the color?

Comment: @Mahi That will totally fail. You need to follow the structure. The `<tr>` or `<td>` or `<th>` tags do not live out of `<table>`.

Comment: @Nda.S Background colour of individual block.